ImportError: cannot import name 'Product' from 'models' || FastAPI + smtp,
I trying to create email sender but i get an error when i want to import Product
ImportError: cannot import name 'Product' from 'models'
from fastapi import FastAPI
from models import Product

#email
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, UploadFilem, File, Form
from fastapi_mail import FastMail, MessageSchema, ConnectionConfig
from pydantic import EmailStr, BaseModel
from typing import List


app = FastAPI()


class EmailSchema(BaseModel):
    email: List[EmailStr]

class EmailContent(BaseModel):
    message: str
    subject: str


@app.post("email/{product_id}")
async def send_email(product_id: int, content: EmailContent):
    
    product = await Product.get(id = product_id)
    supplier = await product.supplied_by
    supplier_email = [supplier.email]

    html = f"""
        """

    message = MessageSchema(
            subject=content.subject,
            recipients=supplier_email,
            body=html,
            subtype="html"
            )
        
    fm = FastMail(conf)
    await fm.send_message(message)
    return {"status": "OK"}

fix an error ImportError: cannot import name 'Product' from 'models'

Do you have class Product in models.py?

This is not FastAPI-related nor a [mre]. I bet you can shrink your example down to just from models import Product.

You have not shared the models.py file, which we need to see.

Your directory layout and how you're running the project would also be useful; i.e. have you added an __init__.py file to the current directory? Have you tried using from .models import Product instead? How about from yourcurrentmodule.models ... Are you importing inside a defined module?
